# StartActivity Performance

Tags: android

My app started to get really slow between activities and I started to investigate
from the time I run StartActivty until onCreate in that activity start, can take up to 1000ms

Can anyone tell me what this could be

I tried to remove everything in oncreate and it's not it.. it's simply the 800ms to 1000ms before it even runs onCreate

Comment: Without seeing any code this can't be answered. Also it depends a lot on the hardware. The best answer you can get is measure and see what takes so long. Try using [traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) for example.

Comment: slow device/emulator, onPause code of prev Activity, lots od data in prev Activity(so GC has a lots of work), ...

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be hidden in your xml layout files. Xml parsing itself is resource consuming. So check them out.

Comment: The 1000ms is before setContentView

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the application in 4.x device. Please the Setting -> Developer Option-> Don't Keep Activites enabled or not.
If it's enabled your application might be slow.
Please check out the option.